# Anyone knows that the file values-sw580?

Tags: android, file

I find an strange file named `values-sw580` in my Android contact code .I don't know what is this for and why it calls this way.Anyone know about it ?:） tell me please.thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swXXX qualifier declares the smallest screen width in dips that the resources in the directory are designed for.

so values-sw580 defines resources for a device which is at least 580 dips wide.

Answer (score 0):

New size qualifiers were introduced in Android 3.2. Check out [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).